# require_once of function file in a header

Tags: php

ive got an global `include/header.php` file like:

UPDATE
folder structure :

```
 /
   include/
            header.php
            functions.php

   content/
            show.php
```

**include/header.php**

```
<?php
  require_once('functions.php');
  $settings = blaa;
     ....
?>
```

**include/functions.php**

```
<?php
    function hello()
    {
      echo "hello world";
    }
?>
```

and now a content file like `content/show.php`

**content/show.php**

```
<?php
  require_once('../include/header.php');

  echo "show page want to say: ";
  hello();
?>
```

and now if i look in the apache error_log `call to undefined function in content/show.php on line...`

i cannot find out why :-/

Greetings

Comment: I guess its in the folder structure. Perhaps your server is hiding the errors for including the file, and thus it is not included. if you put something like "echo 111;" in the header file, does it show?

Comment: youre right... the include of the function.php failed from the header.php but how to fix this ? :-/

Comment: Show us your folder structure. In your code it means content and include folder are on the same level

Comment: look in the top post, i updated it

Comment: strange. This should just include fine. I even tested

Comment: @HugoDelsing Same for me

Comment: Yes, this should work. What does the error log say before that message you've provided? Any other errors, warnings?

Comment: Also, can you add following to the very beginning (before `require_once`) of `show.php` and check what errors this will give: `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 'On');`.

Comment: Maybe your php.ini include_path isn't configured properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you tweak your header.php code to this:

```
<?php

    define('INCDIR', str_replace('\\', '/', dirname(__FILE__)));
    require_once(INCDIR . '/functions.php');
```

It wont matter where you include it from it will constantly find the right path to the include folder

Comment: Can't see any reason to do that when `functions.php` is located in the same folder along with `header.php`.

Comment: @AndrejsCainikovs His code works for me,  I can only imagine differences in PHP versions / server setups

Comment: @Roby No problem, can I ask.. what version of PHP are you using?

Comment: @AndrejsCainikovs I know how this works, my issue is his code works totally fine for me as is! I do have a vague memory of this issue happening in past versions of PHP but I could be dreaming :)

Comment: hey, its php version 5.3.3 :) greetings